# Is Description field required in Restriction Rules?

Tags: fields, restrictionrules

When Restriction Rule is created on UI, it is possible to create it without description.

But if you try to retrieve it and deploy to another org, the following error is displayed:

```
Error  Keep_Tasks_Private  Required field is missing: description

ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Deploy failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a bug in UI since [it is mentioned in Metadata API that a description is required](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.restriction_rules.meta/restriction_rules/meta_restrictionrule.htm)

> description   string  Required. The description of the rule.

Update: Salesforce published a Known Issue for this

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V00000214nIQAQ

Comment: nice contribution - have you reported it to SFDC Support? (or checked for a Known Issue)

Comment: not yet, but was going to

Comment: opened a case in Salesforce support

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/case-view?caseId=500Hx000004FlcDIAS Case #42821283